# How to use should in past tense

Tags: sentence-choice

I have this sentence.

> If shouldn't helped him this tragedy might not happen.

Should I include *have* after **shouldn't**? **shouldn't have helped** doesn't sound fine to me. **shouldn't helped** either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you wouldn't use *shouldn't* in that sentence. The subject needs to be used there instead:

> If **we** had helped him, this tragedy might not have happened.

Or, we can use the present tense, if there is still time to avert the tragedy:

> If Paul helps him, this tragedy might not happen.

We might work in a *should*, like this:

> We should help him; otherwise, a tragedy might happen.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use **should** in **past tense** in the context that helping him would have prevented a tragedy, you might phrase it as

> I should have helped him. If I had, this tragedy might not have
>   happened.

But since you used **shouldn't** and not **should**, maybe you believe that your help might have caused the tragedy, and in that context you could phrase it as

> I shouldn't have helped him. If I hadn't, this tragedy might not have
>   happened.